# Differential equation with Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question**

$f:[1,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable with $f(x)=(x\ln{x}-\ln{x^2})f'(x) \hspace{0.5em}\forall x \in [1,2]$,

Find $f$.

**My solution**

We can see that $f(1)=f(2)=0$ and $f$ satisfies Rolle's Theorem on $[1,2]$ so $\exists\xi\in(1,2):f'(\xi)=0$

We can also notice that $f(\xi)=0 $ from there we can notice that this action can be done repeatedly hinting that $f$ is constant.

$f$ is continuous on $[1,2]$ so from the Min-max theorem we know $f$ has a minimum value $m$ and maximum value $M$.

The possible values for the function's extrema are the edges $\{1,2\}$ where $f(1)=f(2)=0$ and it's critical point $\xi$ where we also have $f(\xi)=0$.

So in the end $m=M=0$ so $f$ is constant with $f(x)=0 \hspace{0.5em} \forall x \in [1,2]$

**Thoughts**

This is the first time an exercise like this came up and I feel like this isn't the optimal way to go here. I feel like I noticed it's a constant a bit too late and a better solution could arise had that realization happened earlier.

Comment: If the function is not constant, it must have an interior strict maximum or minimum point.